# How to find out what is blocking inbound traffic on Windows when firewall is turned off

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

I have a personal Windows 10 Pro that I use for some C# development. When I test my ASP.NET Core app, I run it using Visual Studio (which in turn starts IIS Express).

I needed to test how my app is going to behave when requests are made from "another machine". I did all the appropriate changes to expose IIS Express to the local network (binding rules + firewall rules) - no rocket science, I used to do that before and used to work without issues.

However this time I am stuck. When I run the app, I can access it through localhost, however if I try from another machine - nothing. Additional info - the app is listening on port 44311.

What I tried to diagnose the issue:

- `netstat -a -n` - I get 2 entries:

  - `TCP    0.0.0.0:44311          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
  - `TCP    [::]:44311             [::]:0                 LISTENING`
- (pwsh) `Get-NetTCPConnection` => `::           44311     ::      0          Listen`
- wireshark with filter set to `tcp.port == 44311` - when requests are made, I get some chatter, so clearly network interface is getting the data, although I cannot really decifer what it says to me:

[image: wireshark]

- CurrPorts (by NirSoft) shows the listening ports, but if I make a request:

  - from the network - no activity (visible only 2 first rows),
  - locally to `https://localhost:44311` then I do see activity:

[image: currports]

I am looking for any idea - where else can I check what might be blocking my traffic?

During my tests windows defender and virus protection were shut down.

Comment: "however if I try from another machine" - This other machine is on the intranet network or outside of the intranet network?

Comment: Your Wireshark pic shows two TCP connection attempts from .37 to .113. It shows that the TCP SYN packets are being sent, but there are no TCP SYN+ACK replies, so it's as if the SYN's aren't getting to .113, or .113 isn't replying to them with TCP (your filter wouldn't show any potential ICMP responses, such as "port unreachable"). Do you have a VPN configured? Many VPNs can be configured for "full tunnel" mode, which forces all traffic to go through the VPN tunnel, blocking you from talking to things on your own LAN other than getting a DHCP lease and sending VPN traffic to the router.

Comment: @Ramhound: this is intranet - my home WiFi network.

Comment: @Spiff: I do have a number of VPNs set up on my computer, however none of them were connected during my tests. But just in case I went through all the configurations for the VPNs and switched to split tunnel (except one because I could not find the option). Unfortunately, this did not help. Any idea how to diagnose what may be preventing my machine from SYN-ACK? Also, I added to my wireshark filter ` || icmp `, but no change in the wireshark's list of packets.